# Increase Linewidth on zoom THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I try to process dynamic 2d rainfields (comparable to [this](http://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/qpf/fill_94qwbg.gif?1472560361889), just that I process the data dynamically and animate it).

Until now I found that the best fitting solution for my project is creating horizontal *LineSegments*, so I can process the data set line by line and give each *LineSegment* a color. I store everything I need in a *BufferGeometry*.

**Now my problem is**
that when I implement a zoom by simply reducing the z-index of the camera, the spaces between those lines become visible, because the lines dont become thicker.

I read that the linewidth-parameter of a LineSegment object is inaccessible on Windows so is there any other way I could try?

Comment: @WestLangley: Works for me!

Comment: @genpfault Thank you for your many other edits!  :) Deleted previous comment.

Comment: Have a look at `Three.MeshLine`: https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine